# A biblioteca do Python Tkinter ainda existe?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Eu uso ubuntu e como essa biblioteca não vem instalado por padrão no linux, estava tentando instalar ela via Pip porém não consigo achar ela no site oficial do Python.

Comment: De acordo com a documentação [https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html]: "Both Tk and tkinter are available on most Unix platforms, as well as on Windows systems. (Tk itself is not part of Python; it is maintained at ActiveState.)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende da versão do Python ou Ubuntu que você está rodando, entre outras coisas, mas sim, o Tkinter ainda existe.

Se você estiver usando **Python 3**:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Se você estiver rodando o **Python 2**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Instalando a última versão estável diretamente (tive problemas de compatibilidade com algumas bibliotecas na versão 3.7):

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk
```

Dependendo da sua versão de Ubuntu o processo pode ser um pouco diferente. Vi um usuário com a versão `16.04` que precisou fazer o seguinte:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev
$ pyenv install 3.6.2
```

Se nada disso funcionar pode ser preciso adicionar um repositório:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

P.S. 1 - Lembrando que o **Pyenv** é uma ferramenta de gerenciamento de versões que pode ser instalada através [deste repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

P.S. 2 - O import do Tkinter no Python 2 é diferente do import no Python 3.

```
#Python 3
import tkinter

#Python 2
import Tkinter
```

Comment: "3.6" é um Python antiguinho já - o último estável é o 3.7

Comment: Sim sim, mas como disse eu tive problemas com o 3.7 alguns meses atrás e precisei fazer downgrade. Depois fiquei com medo de fazer um novo upgrade pra ver se já está resolvido haha